# Adding elements in array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, octave

I have to add elements in array.

I have function:

```
 function d = kronDel(j,k)

if j == k
    d = 1;
else
    d = 0;
end
```

And i have n=0:31.

I tried this:

```
x2=j*kronDel(n-2,0);
```

Why doesnt this work?

I only get x2=0;

Comment: What is the desired output? As written, `kronDel` only outputs a scalar, so the result you’re getting isn’t surprising.

Comment: i need to have x2=[0,0,j,0,0,0,0...to the 31 all 0s]
j=sqrt(-1)

Comment: Note that most kroneker deltas in mathematics do not get translated to code as you do. A kronecker delta on a matrix, is literally `matrix(j)`, no need to create a copy and set the rest to zero. A single element of the array is by definition a kronecker delta on the array.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a kronecker delta function but you don't need it.

```
x2 = j(n==2)
```

or, if you want to keep the zeros

```
x2 = j.*(n==2)
```

If you really want to make the function, just adapt it to:

```
function d = kronDel(j,k)
d = j==k;
```

From your comment: "x2=[0,0,j,0,0,0,0...to the 31 all 0s] j=sqrt(-1)"

```
x2=zeros(1,31);x2(3)=i
```

Comment: But my argument j should be a vector. And fucnction returns me only 1 value for first member of vector.

Comment: I have no idea what you try to say. I edited my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: i have to get x2 from function, not like that. y=i * kronDel(n) and that n is  vector from 0 to 31, and y should be vector too

Comment: Make the function `kronDel.m` like I posted above (`d=j==k`) and run `n=0:31;y=i*kronDel(n-2,0)`